# How to get id or values of object in layout using Layout inflater?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

Im try Layout Inflater, it's work. Then a try to define the id of object in the view of the layout was inflated. but how to get the values or id of object in these layout? here xml code..

XML hidden.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
android:id="@+id/hiddenLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Saya teks 1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox1" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox2" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox3" />
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Satu" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dua" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tiga" />
</RadioGroup>
```

XML Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="Add View" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="Remove View" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="value" />
```

Java

```
private int jumlahteks = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View buttonAdd = findViewById(R.id.add);
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

    View buttonRemove = findViewById(R.id.remove);
    buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.add:
        jumlahteks = jumlahteks + 1;
    //Check if the Layout already exists
    //LinearLayout hiddenLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);
        //Inflate the Hidden Layout Information View
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearhost);
        View hiddenInfo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hidden, myLayout, false);
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) hiddenInfo.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // Update the TextView Text
        myTextView.setId(jumlahteks);
        myTextView.setText(jumlahteks);

        myLayout.addView(hiddenInfo);

    //Get References to the TextView
    break;

    case R.id.remove:
        View myView = findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView.getParent();
        parent.removeView(myView);

        break;
        // More buttons go here (if any) ...
    }
```

How to get id or values of object in hidden.xml?? and set the values, im work with this layout inflater to create dinamycaly views and grab the values of each object in that views was inflated. Thanks for help and advice..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, but it sounds like you want to have hiddenLayout in your main layout, and want it to be hidden sometimes.  Try including hiddenLayout in the appropriate place in main.xml with the include tag, set a name for it using android:id="", and then you can just use findViewById like on the other elements.  To hide or show it, call setVisibility(VISIBLE or INVISIBLE).

EDIT: Your hidden.xml doesn't have a root type.  It looks like you are missing a "<" as well, so maybe you just didn't include it when you copy/pasted.  I would make a Hidden.java class that is a subclass of a type of layout, say a LinearLayout and has accessors to the fields that you want.  Then you can use the subclass as follows in your xml .  You can then call

```
Hidden hiddenLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hidden, null)
```

to get your hidden layout, and then use your accessors like hidden.getTextView1() to get access to the things inside.

You could also just make the root type a LinearLayout and use

```
LinearLayout hiddenLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hidden, null) 
TextView text = hiddenLayout.findViewById(R.id.TextView1)
```

but IMO subclassing is better because it allows you to encapsulate behavior for your hidden layout beyond what is possible in the xml.

Comment: no, im using Layout Inflater to add the hiddenLayout in mainLayot, not using setVisibility. I'm using findviewbyid to get object in hiddenLayout.xml, but how to set these object id. I'm to try using looping to create views of hiddenLayout dinamycally on runtime.

Comment: I'd recommend using the xml files whenever possible, because it allows for better code organization and encapsulation.  But, if must add the layout programmatically, see my edit above.